JAXB Unmarshalling Issues in Spring Web Service
I successfully generated the WSDL in Spring based on the existing WSDL definition I had. This was accomplished without any issues, and the generated WSDL aligns with my expectations. However, despite this successful generation, I am still facing challenges with the SOAP requests.
When I invoke the web service using SOAP UI and pass values into the RequestorID, RequestSub, and RequestStatus fields, I receive JAXBElement as null.
WSDL Definition The relevant portion of the WSDL is as follows:
<wsdl:message name="ActiveInput"> 
   <wsdl:part name="RequestorID" type="cla:RequestorIDType"/> 
   <wsdl:part name="RequestSub" type="req:RequestSubType"/> 
   <wsdl:part name="RequestStatus" type="req:RequestStatusType"/>
</wsdl:message>

Code:
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "test") 
@ResponsePayload 
public JAXBElement test(
   @RequestPayload JAXBElement requestorID, 
   @RequestPayload JAXBElement requestSub, 
   @RequestPayload JAXBElement requestModifyStatus
) {
   RequestorIDSimpleType requestorIDObj = requestorID.getValue(); 
   LOG.info("Description: {}", requestorIDObj.getDescription()); 
   LOG.info("User: {}", requestorIDObj.getUser()); }

Also i see this message: Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@be9e5ce] maps request to endpoint [public jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement<test.GeneralResponseType> test.activate(jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement<test.RequestorIDType>,jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement<test.RequestSubType>,jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement<testl.RequestStatusType>)] Field not found in XML string.
I expected the service to successfully extract the values from the RequestorID, RequestSub, and RequestStatus fields without any null values.
